# Instance method to return image parameters individual values

Tags: iphone, methods

I want to get image parameters x and y in return by calling an instance method. I need to send an integer value from 0 to 3, according to which corresponding result to fetched.
Below is the code i am trying to use.

```
-(int)imgSize:(int)y parameters:(int)m
{   
if(n == 0)
{

    return  y= 320;
    return m = 50;
}

if(n == 1)
{
    return  y= 728;
    return m = 90;
}

if(n == 2)
{
    return  y= 300;
    return m = 250;
}

if(n == 3)
{
    return  y= 468;
    return m = 60;
}
return 0;
}
```

What i am not getting is how to send the value of n so that it can give required response.
Please guide for the above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood right, you confuse input with output, so:

```
-(CGSize)imgSizeWithParameters:(int)n
{
CGSize m = CGSizeMake(0,0);   
if(n == 0)
{
    m = CGSizeMake(50,320); 
}
else if(n == 1)
{
    m = CGSizeMake(90,728); 
}
else if(n == 2)
{
    m = CGSizeMake(250,320);   
}
else if(n == 3)
{
    m = CGSizeMake(60,468);
}
return m;
}
```

for get the parameters:

```
CGSize size = [self imgSizeWithParameters:x]; //where x is 0,1,2 or 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSMutableArray*)imgSize:(int)y parameters:(int)m
{   
if(n == 0)
{
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber   numberWithInt:320],[NSNumber numberWithInt:50],nil];
    return tmpArray;
}

if(n == 1)
{
NSMutableArray *tmpArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber   numberWithInt:728],[NSNumber numberWithInt:90],nil];
return tmpArray;
}

if(n == 2)
{

NSMutableArray *tmpArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber   numberWithInt:300],[NSNumber numberWithInt:250],nil];
return tmpArray;
}

if(n == 3)
{

NSMutableArray *tmpArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber   numberWithInt:468],[NSNumber numberWithInt:60],nil];
return tmpArray;
}

}
```

Comment: I know it's probably a little excessive, but that could be cleaned up pretty significantly to: `return @[@(320), @(50)];`, etc.

Comment: definitely,..  i wryt it in lil hurry.. sorry for that...happy Valentyns day )

Comment: Happy valentine day to you also, i will also look at it tomorrow in office.